# regex quandry - for word matching

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am out of my depth here, currently reading the tutorials and using python to learn regex.

I have a website where a php file http://www.example.com/showme.php?user=JOHN will load the visitor page of JOHN. However I want to let John have his own vanity URL like john.example.com and rewrite it to http://www.example.com/showme.php?user=JOHN .

I know it can be done and after fiddling with it it seems lighttpd mod_rewrite is the way to go. Now I am stumped as I am trying to come up with regex to match!

```
rewrite ("^![www]\.example\.com" => "www\.example\.com\?user=###");
```

I am playing with python re module to test out several ways of getting the john from john.example.com and recognize when the first segment of url is not www and then redirect. Above was my trial. Am I even in the right continent!

Any help will be appreciated in

1. recognizing when first part of url before the first `.` is not `www` and is something else - so that example.com won't stump it.
2. getting the first part of the url before first `.` and tag it to `user=###`

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lighttpd's mod-rewrite module. Add this to your `lighttpd.conf` file:

```
$HTTP["host"] != "www.example.com" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^([^.]+)\.example\.com$" {
        url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/?$" => "/showme.php?user=%1"
        )
    }
}
```

For an `href` value like `/dir/page.php` the domain part of the link gets automatically added from the current request as shown in the browser's address bar. So, if you had used `www.example.com`; the link would point to `htp://www.example.com/dir/page.php` and likewise for `john.example.com`.

For all your links to point at `www.example.com`, you need to be accessing the page using `www`. This would be possible only if you do an external redirect from the vanity URL to the actual one i.e. users can still use the shortened URL but they would get redirected to the actual one.

```
$HTTP["host"] != "www.example.com" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^([^.]+)\.example\.com$" {
        url.redirect = (
            "^/?$" => "http://www.example.com/showme.php?user=%1"
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ravi. I tried this and it does redirect to showme.php?user=... appropriately but now the css for the main page does not load and any links on the page now try to load john.example.com/joinus.php and so on instead of www.example.com/joinus.php . I guess I should go and correct my sloppy programming and set all the hrefs appropriately. Any advise will however be well appreciated.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks a bunch. I was pulling my hair when it was not working but then realized I did not include mod_redirect in the setup! It works now. I am still wet behind the ears with regex.

Comment: Glad to know this helped.

Comment: See it in action at [link](http://photographer.rue16.com) . That should redirect correctly.

Comment: Really nice! Good luck with your website.

Comment: Could you please open a new question and post the link here? It's difficult to understand code blocks in comments. Thanks.